# Долгая анимация нажатия ImageVIew

Tags: java, android

Есть кнопка ImageView и анимация её нажатия. Когда я зажимаю ImageView, анимация быстро завершается. Как сделать, чтобы анимация уменьшения и прозрачности, не завершалась пока я не уберу палец с ImageView?

```
public class NaturesFragment1 extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.natures_fragment1,container,false);

    ImageView button1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.human_button)
            .asBitmap()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .into(button1);
    button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.click_animation1));
                // Do what you want
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                //view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.click_animation1));
                Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(getActivity(), SkullActivity.class));
                startActivity(intent);
                // Do what you want
                return true;
            }


            return false;
        }
    });

    return view;

}
```

**anim_file.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha = "1.0"
        android:toAlpha = "0.7"
        android:duration = "10"

        android:fillAfter="true">
    </alpha>
    <scale
        android:fromXScale = "1"
        android:toXScale = "0.9"
        android:fromYScale = "1"
        android:toYScale = "0.9"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration = "50"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        >
    </scale>
</set>
```

Comment: выставить ее в режим повторения на бесконечность раз

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы используете `AnimationSet` (т.к. вы привели только огрызок кода, а не весь файл).    

Выставьте у каждой из анимаций в сете `android:repeatCount="infinite"`

Comment: Спасибо, только теперь анимация стала повторятся. Как можно сделать, чтобы она воспроизвелась один раз и осталась в конечном состоянии, а не запускалась снова и снова? @metalurgus

Comment: установите `android:fillAfter="true"` Для каждой анимации в сете. И уберите то, что только что добавили

Comment: не получается, анимация просто проигрывается один раз и возвращается в стандартное состояние ImageView . @metalurgus

Comment: Покажите, текущий код анимации полностью

Comment: Обновил @metalurgus

Comment: попробуйте у самого `<set` добавить `android:fillAfter="true"`

Comment: Большое спасибо! @metalurgus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У самого `<set` добавьте `android:fillAfter="true"`